# Domino XPages Import cannot be resolved

Tags: classpath, xpages

A Domino XPages project I inherited is stating three errors:

```
The import com.ibm.xylem cannot be resolved
The import com.ibm.compat cannot be resolved
The import com.ibm.security cannot be resolved
```

I have ensured the correct XPages plugins have been installed.  I have also removed the jars from the build path and re-inserted them and also cleaned the project but I still have these errors.  I have also searched the internet for these jars but cannot find any.

What is going wrong with jars and project?

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you don't have these JARs and are trying to find them?

Comment: Please check the build path for the library *rt.jar*. You can find it in the folder "<DOMINO>\jvm<\lib"

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use non-standard libraries inside a Java agent, i think you have to import them in another way. When you open the agent in Domino Designer perspective, you'll see a drowdown button "Import". If you have, for example, the additional libraries as jar files, use Import > Archive.